# Predefined type list passed to a std::variant

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, typelist, std-variant

Is there any way to create a pre-defined type list, and use those types in a std::variant in c++ 17?  Here is what I'm trying to do, it compiles, but doesn't work as I was hoping:

```
template < class ... Types > struct type_list {};
using valid_types = type_list< int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, double, std::string >;
using value_t = std::variant< valid_types >;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way:

```
template<class... Types> 
std::variant<Types...> as_variant(type_list<Types...>);

using value_t = decltype(as_variant(valid_types{}));
```

Comment: Thank you for you response, I believe this is going to work for me, I just need to absorb exactly what's going on here.  Please correct me if I am wrong here.

Comment: You are declaring a function that returns a variant of types that accepts as a parameter the type list aliased by the valid types.  And the decltype is simply returning what as_variant would return?  Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: @DavidMassat Yes, you got it right. Note that the `as_variant` function definition is not necessary here, the declaration is enough to make use of `decltype`.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done by having `type_list` send `Types` into the metafunction (`std::variant`):

```cpp
template < class ... Types > struct type_list {
    template < template < class... > class MFn >
    using apply = MFn< Types... >;
};
// Optional. For nicer calling syntax:
template < template < class... > class MFn, class TypeList >
using apply = typename TypeList::template apply< MFn >;

using valid_types = type_list< int16_t, int32_t, int64_t, double, std::string >;
using value_t = apply< std::variant, valid_types >;
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/cpRvTJ)

Comment: You would want your `apply` to be a stand-alone metafunction rather than a member if the type list.

Comment: As `value_type` is a concrete type in that context, your `typename` and `template` keywords in `value_t` line aren't needed I think.

Comment: @Justin syntax would be better, you won't need `template apply`. Same reason why `get` is not a member of `std::tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

Using Boost.MP11, this is [`mp_rename`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_renamel_y):

```cpp
using value_t = mp_rename< valid_types, std::variant >;
```

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/yMAkFO)

---

Alternatively, [`mp_apply`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_applyf_l) is the same operation with the operands flipped, if you find it more readable:

```cpp
using value_t = mp_apply< std::variant, valid_types >;
```

Comment: I'd advertise this as `mp_rename<valid_types, std::variant>` (same thing, just reversed parameters, but "rename" is more direct in this case). But yeah, this is definitely the best choice. Great library.

Comment: @Barry What do you mean by "more direct"? Is the name more obvious?

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. We're renaming `type_list` to `variant` basically. `apply` has different connotation to me. But either way, `mp_apply` is I think defined in terms of `mp_rename` so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest, most concise way I know of to do this:

```
template < class ... Types > struct type_list {
  template<template<class...>class Z>
  using apply_to = Z<Types...>;
};

using value_t = value_types::apply_to<std::variant>;
```

you can get fancier.  For example:

```
template<class T, template<class...>class Z>
struct transcribe_parameters;
template<class T, template<class...>class Z>
using transcribe_parameters_t = typename
  transcribe_parameters<T,Z>::type;
template<template<class...>class Zin, class...Ts, template<class...>class Zout>
struct transcribe_parameters<Zin<Ts...>, Zout> {
  using type=Zout<Ts...>;
};
```

which gives you:

```
using value_t = transcribe_parameters_t<value_types, std::variant>;
```

but, having that be a built-in feature of `type_list` doesn't seem unreasonable.

Comment: Please explain the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're fine with augmenting your type_list structure:

```
template <class ... Types> struct type_list {
    using variant_type = std::variant< Types...>;
};
```

If you want it as a separate funcion:

```
template <class T> struct type_list_variant;
template <class... Types> struct type_list_variant<type_list<Types...>> {
    using type = std::variant<Types...>;
};

template <class T>
using type_list_variant_t = typename type_list_variant<T>::type;
```